# How to fix this unchecked cast error when using generics?

Tags: java, list, generics, kotlin

In my class I have a list containing TopicNodes. The nodes of those list should extend from the Message class. In the method `findNode` within the list of nodes there is searched for a node with a specific topic and if it matches it is being returned. The Java compiler complains about the TopicNode being converted to a TopicNode of type `T` as it is possible that it is not of type `T`. What is the best way to solve this?

```
private val nodes: MutableList<TopicNode<*>>

init {
    this.nodes = ArrayList()
}

private fun <T : Message> findNode(topic: String): TopicNode<T>? {
    for (node in nodes) {
        if (node.topic == topic) {
            return node as TopicNode<T> // Unchecked cast: TopicNode<*> to TopicNode<T>
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: *The nodes of those list should extend from the Message class.* - why the `<*>` then?

Comment: Maybe the question then should be: `how to define that the objects in a list should extend from another class?` I do not know how to do this @TimCastelijns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this should parameterise the class, not the method.

The code in the question must come from a class, which isn't shown.  Each instance of that class holds a list of nodes.  And to judge from the method, each class holds nodes of a particular message type.  But the method a) requires the caller to know in advance which type, and b) allows it to be called on the same instance for different types, which would make no sense!

Instead, you can tell the compiler that each instance holds nodes of a particular type, by giving a type parameter on the class, instead of the method:

```
class MyClass<T : Message> {
    private val nodes: MutableList<TopicNode<T>>

    init {
        this.nodes = ArrayList()
    }

    private fun findNode(topic: String): TopicNode<T>? {
        for (node in nodes) {
            if (node.topic == topic) {
                return node // No need to cast
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

That way, the method already knows what type its nodes are, and can return them directly.

In fact, the class could then be simplified to:

```
class MyClass<T : Message> {
    private val nodes: MutableList<TopicNode<T>> = ArrayList()

    private fun findNode(topic: String)
        = nodes.find{ it.topic == topic }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting this out there, just in case it fits the OP's use-case and they don't really need the 'extends generics' on their list. Sometimes you don't see the forest for the trees

```
private val nodes: MutableList<TopicNode<Message>>

private fun findNode(topic: String) = nodes.firstOrNull{ it.topic == topic}
```

If TopicNode is covariant then e.g. a `TopicNode<MyMessage>` could be  added to `nodes` otherwise compiler would produce an error.

How do i know if TopicNode is covariant? It is covariant if TopicNode is declared as:

```
class TopicNode<Out T> {
```

It comes with a set of restrictions on that class. For more information on that topic https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance

I do find the question from the comments interesting: *how to define that the objects in a list should extend from another class?* Not sure whether that is possible without going the route gidds did in their answer

Comment: Looks like a great solution. But is it a good idea to specify `Message` as type for the `TopicNode`? Can f.e. a TopicNode `MyMessage` that extends from `Message` being added to the list?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution myself. You can use `.filterIsInstance<T>()` for a list filtering the items of type `T` in the list.

This leads to the following solution:

```
 private fun <T : Message> findNode(topic: String): TopicNode<T>? {
    val messageNodes: List<TopicNode<T>> = nodes.filterIsInstance<TopicNode<T>>()
    for (node in messageNodes) {
        if (node.topic == topic) {
            return node
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

It checks for items in the list being of type `TopicNode<T>` where `T` extends from `Message`.

Comment: Your code could be written as: `return nodes.filterIsInstance<TopicNode<T>>().firstOrNull {it.topic == topic} ` in kotlin

Comment: @Klyner you are looking for one particular element, but you filter the whole list beforehand. this would be shorter: `private fun <T: Message> findNode(topic: String) = nodes.firstOrNull {
        (it as? TopicNode<T>)?.topic == topic
    }` and require only one iteration. but then it becomes obvious that the original problem still exists if `nodes` is of type `MutableList<TopicNode<*>>`